# Remove date in amsppt

Tags: amstex, date

How to remove the 'date' when the following is used in the preamble ? Any help is appreciated.

```
\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}
\magnification=\magstep1                        %<====
\hsize6.5truein\vsize8.9truein                  %<====
\NoRunningHeads
\loadeusm
\usepackage{titling}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE - a complete compilable small document where you can point out what date you want not to be there. You can format the code by selecting it and using the `{}` edit option on the menu bar.

Comment: This was the code in the .tex file:
\date December 9, 2015
\enddate

Comment: You should edit your question to include a complete compilable document with that offending line. That said, try `\date \enddate` (with nothing in between) in the source file.

Comment: Unrelated to the question being asked, but `\usepackage` is a LaTeX declaration, it doesn’t belong here.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti And `\documentstyle` ??!!

Comment: @cfr: No, `\documentstyle` *is* an AMS-TeX macro.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Did they do that just to be maximally confusing?

Comment: @cfr: M. Spivak and L. Lamport were developing their respective TeX formats more or less in parallel.  The idea of a “document style” was common to both approaches; it was, in a sense, “in the air”.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I did try that. And \date{} too. Still it isn't working.

Comment: @Eureka Good thing you got an answer then, but isn't it?

Comment: @cfr -- `amstex` predates latex by several years.  the first version was out by the end of 1980.  `\documentstyle` was named quite independently by spivak.  i can't account for the convergence, but i do have the records for `amstex` that demonstrate independent development.  (dick palais was lamport's thesis advisor at brandeis, and palais was also the chair of the ams board of trustees when knuth delivered his gibbs lecture to the ams annual meeting in january 1979, and the ams contingent sent to stanford to learn tex, summer 1979, was at palais' urging.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton `they` was deliberately ambiguous since I had no idea who used it first.

Comment: I got this from a colleague to troubleshoot. I tried all my gimmicks to make it 'nicer'.

Comment: @cfr -- fair enough.  (i just happened to be at stanford with the ams contingent in july 1979.)  i've got a paper on the subject of "math communication with tex" appearing in the next issue of "visible language" that touches on the history.  when i have full bibliographic info, i'll post it in the chat.

Comment: @Eureka -- if your colleague insists on using `amstex`, s/he really needs to read the documentation, which is the book "joy of tex" by michael spivak.  sadly, it's not free or on line; i'm trying to get the ams to release it, but have no prediction about whether the effort might be successful.

Comment: @Eureka: If you have a TeXLive, `texdoc amsguide` should bring up a concise, but useable guide.  Not comparable to Spivak’s book, of course, but…  BTW, _The Joy of TeX_ was first published in 1982, whereas the first edition of _LaTeX: A Document Preparation System_ didn’t appear until 1985.  Is this correct?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti -- there were earlier "informal" versions of documentation for both amstex and latex, but even so, amstex was earlier.  (i think the dates are correct, but i'm nowhere near my bookshelf to check.)

Answer (score 5):

I haven’t been authoring AMS-TeX documents for almost twenty years, but I can say that the following code *is* compiled by plain TeX…

```
\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}
\magnification=\magstep1
\hsize6.5truein\vsize8.9truein
\NoRunningHeads
\loadeusm
\topmatter
\title The Gnus\endtitle
\author Arthur Uther Thor\endauthor
% \date July~17, 2016\enddate
\endtopmatter
\document
Gnus are big.
\enddocument
```

… and does *not* show the date as long as the relevant line is commented out.

**Addition:** Anyway, may I kindly but warmly suggest that you switch to LaTeX + one of the AMS classes, *e.g.*, `amsart`?  Do something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % not actually necessary, but I use it by habit
% ... more packages as needed

\title{The Gnus}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}
% \date{\today} % uncomment to see where the date would wind up

\pagestyle{plain} % instead of \NoRunningHeads

% ... More declarations ...

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Gnus are big.

\end{document}
```

This should produce an output essentially equivalent to that of the first sample code.

Comment: thanks for fielding this question.  i nearly fell off my chair when i saw the question.  is someone still *starting* to use tex via `amstex`?  incredible!

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Sigh… Nostalgia…